# How to bundle scripts that will be called within a "new Function()"

Tags: webpack

Let's say we have this very simple script :

```
// script.js

return {foo : "bar"};
```

This script is meant to be executed within a `new Function()` like this :

```
const res = new Function(`return {foo : "bar"};`) // res = {foo : "bar"}
```

But when I bundle this script with webpack, res becomes `undefined`. I guess its because webpack's output contains a self invoking function.

How can I configure webpack to make it work with a `new Function()` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, with a webpack plugin. See this [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10060).